# How to convert empty string to zero?

Tags: php

I would like to convert empty strings to zero as an INT. Is it possible not to use "if" statements?

```php
$string = "";
echo $string; // The result must be 0 as INT.
```

Comment: *"Is it possible not to use "if" statements?"* - Which `if` is that?

Comment: $string = "";
echo intval($string);

Comment: just revisited this - just wondering - what's the benefit of this vs using return result from `empty()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only real way is to [typecast](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
<?php
    $str = '';
    echo (int)$str;
```

However, if this is dynamically assigned then you'll have to use an if statement. But fear not, [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) exists:

```
echo (empty($str) ? 0 : $str);
```

With the thanks of **Dharman**, we can [Elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) it up a bit:

```
echo $str ?: 0;
```

Though, note that if `$str` is not defined PHP will throw a undefined notice. For that reason either stick to ternary or ensure the variable is declared before usage.

Comment: :) But fear not :) Love it :)

Answer (score 1):

typecasting will do that

```
 echo (int) $string;
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/CM2q7

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "";

echo intval($string); // the int value of the string
```

For more info, may read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Just typecase the string to int.

```
$string="";
echo (int)$string;
```